# How to add an array in view and pass it to controller

Tags: laravel

Hello i am wondering if its possible to have an array in view blade that is filled with values that user selects and then to be passed to controller. I am asking if its possible to do such a thing and avoid this type of code i already have that works:

```
 foreach ($request->products as $index => $product) {

                $values[] = [
                    'order_id' => $order->id,
                    'product_id' => $product,
                    'amount' => $request->amount[$index],
                ];
```

So for the foreach i dont need to write `$index => $product`

This is the request that comes from view:

```
 $request->validate([
            'order_number' => 'required',
            'client_id' => 'required|exists:clients,id',
            'description' => 'required',
            'products' => 'required|exists:products,id',
            'amount' => 'required',
        ]);
```

And this is the view im using:

```
<div class="row mb-3">
                                <label for="products" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Product') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select name="products[]" id="products" type="text" class="form-control @error('products') is-invalid @enderror" required autocomplete="products">

                                        @foreach($products as $product)

                                            <option value="{{$product->id}}">{{$product->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach

                                    </select>

                                    @error('products')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <label for="amount" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Amount') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="amount" type="text" class="form-control @error('amount') is-invalid @enderror" name="amount[]" required autocomplete="amount">

                                    @error('amount')

                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>

                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question fully, but you just need to send selected IDs to the form handler (controller's method) and then prepare data for a view with selected products.

Comment: @RoboRobok in view there is 1 `select` that gets `product_id` and `product_name` from table order, under it is an input field `amount` both these fields are dynamic user can add more fields with a plus button. When i press submit the values come with request now i need to get the amount value in a way like `for loop` does `$request->amount[$i];` but i should use `foreach` and with foreach i came with this `$request->amount[$index],` method but still dont need this just a simple `foreach`. I was told it can be done with `array` from blade and get it on controller but i dont know how to do that

Comment: Still not sure if I understand. I'd glue them together by mapping (it also gets index in the callback) through products and adding amounts of the same index there. Perhaps there's Laravel Collection's method to do it even easier. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something :)

Comment: @RoboRobok this solution is same as mine but im wondering it can be done without using `$index` https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pass-array-from-blade-to-controller-to-db

Comment: You know, it uses `$index`, because all of these pieces of data are separate. In theory, yes, you could avoid it by naming things in your form. So instead of `foo[]` and `bar[]` you could use `product[0][foo]` and `product[0][bar]` etc. It would prepare the data structure for you, but you'd need to maintain the indexes in your frontend code.

Comment: @RoboRobok do you have any example of it?

Comment: You just need to make sure that your input elements are named with valid indexes in them. I assume that you're having some JS code for adding and removing fields, so any time you remove an entry on client-side, you'd need to reindex things. It can be done, but it's not the cleanest and I'd suggest gluing things together on the backend.

Comment: @RoboRobok yes im using JS to make fields dynamic

Comment: Yeah, so the challenge would be to make sure that these fields are always named properly: `product[0][foo]` / `product[0][bar]` and then the next one would be `product[1][foo]` / `product[1][bar]` etc. If you delete a product indexed as `2`, all products following it would need to be reindexed. I mean if you don't reindex it's not a disaster neither, because they'd still get grouped by backend. But you'd need to know what index to set for the new products. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @RoboRobok We can ignore valid indexes as using a nested structure like this will make it become an associative array. Since we don't need to do this in order, the product id's can be used as the key to the data.

Comment: @MatthewBradley yeah, I know. I wanted it to be a regular array just for making it easier to add new entries (the number of items would serve as the next index). Even for the order it would be okay to use associative array, because the array is built in order as it appears in HTML anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the input name to create an associative array using the `product id` as the key in the array.

You can achieve this by subbing in the product id for the array index and labelling the fields that will go into it.

```
<input type="number" name="products[ {{$product_id}} ][amount]">
<input type="text" name="products[ {{$product_id}} ][otherField]">
```

This will product a structure like

```
["products"]=> array(2) 
    { [101]=> array(2) { 
          ["amount"]=> string(2) "10" ["otherField"]=> string(7) "LABEL 1" }
      [102]=> array(2) { 
          ["amount"]=> string(2) "20" ["otherField"]=> string(7) "LABEL 2" }
    }
```

While you will still have to iterate using `foreach($request->products as $productID => $data)` the data structure is all relational regarding where the data is stored.

Comment: this works great but how can i make it dynamic becuase if i have more then one `product_id` and `amount` the values will be replaced

Comment: You can treat each individual field as an array like `products[ {{$product_id}} ][amount][]` which means that the actual values of these fields will be cast to an array. This will have to be dealt with in the back-end

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to avoid JQuery? It depends on what environment and language you're using. In ASP .NET Core you can use a hidden input field and pass something through as text.

```
<input hidden type="text" name="productsString" value="@JsonSerializer.Serialize(products)" />
```

Then in your controller you can deserialize it (C# example).

```
var products = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Object>(productsString);
```

Maybe that's what you're looking for but it really depends on what you're doing, which I'm not sure about.

Comment: i saw the same thing in Laravel you make a hidden input field

Comment: i want to make similar thing as this but not to use this as a solution using the `$index` https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pass-array-from-blade-to-controller-to-db